# Generic Type Casting and Assignable Types

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm struggling to understand and make sense of using a generic type and casting to it's base form. The code below show's the structure I've got.

```
public interface IBaseRepository : IDisposable
{
    //stuff defined
}

public class BaseRepository : IBaseRepository 
{
    //stuff I want to access
}

public interface IBaseController<TRepo> where TRepo : IBaseRepository
{
    TRepo Repository { get; }
}

public abstract partial class BaseController<TRepo> 
    : Controller,  IBaseController<TRepo> 
        where TRepo : IBaseRepository
{    
    public virtual TRepo Repository { get; protected set; }
}

public interface ISpecificRepository : IBaseRepository
{
}

public class SpecificRepository : BaseRepository, ISpecificRepository 
{
}

public class SpecificController : BaseController<ISpecificRepository>
{
}

// The below cast will only work if the controller 
// specifically implements IBaseController<IBaseRepository>
var _controller = filterContext.Controller as IBaseController<IBaseRepository>
```

I can't cast a controller to IBaseController unless it specifically implements the BaseRepository concreate class and not one of the inheriting classes.

using this example how would I get access to the BaseRepository methods and properties if the controller class is a SpecificController?

I've edited the question to be more specific about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: SpecificController can access public or protected members from its parent BaseController. BaseController in its turn has Repository property. So just access repository through this property.

Comment: @CodeFuller sorry I wasn't being very clear in my question.  I've updated it and hopefully it's more specific about where I'm struggling.

Comment: Make your `IBaseController<TRepo>` covariant - `IBaseController<out TRepo>`

Comment: @Evk that was it thank you.  If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it and start reading up on covariants to get a better understanding on what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

So We could assume that filterContext.Controller is instance of your SpecificController so then

1. SpecificController extends BaseController
2. BaseController extends Controller and implements IBaseController (basing on types)
3. So basing on references Your SpecificController could be used as IBaseController

If You want to use Your controller like IBaseRepository in Your generics specification use code like

```
public class SpecificController : BaseController<IBaseRepository>
```

In generic-type code You have to define right type - You cannot cast objects to parents / children. E.g.

```
class Animal { }
class Dog : Animal { }

List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();
List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();

List<Animal> dogsAsAnimals = dog as List<Animal>; // wrong
List<Dog> animalsAsDogs = animals as List<Dog>; // wrong
IList<Animal> newAnimals = animals as IList<Animal>; // correct
```

and finally

```
animals.Add(new Dog()); // correct
```

so to use Your code:

```
var _controller = filterContext.Controller as IBaseController<ISpecificRepository>
```